# What is the meaning (or the grammatical role) of に in 十分に?

Tags: particle-に

> "時間{じかん}は十分{じゅうぶん}にあるので,　急{いそ}ぐことはありません。"

What is the meaning (or the grammatical role) of に in 十分に?

Answer (score 2):

It changes 十分 into an adverb. Because 十分 is a na-adjective, when you want to change it into an adverb, you put に after it. Note that ある is a verb, so to describe it, you need an adverb.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/adverbs).

EDIT: As naruto mentions, 十分 is also an adverb by itself so the に is optional.

EDIT2: However, based on the [corpus provided by The National](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/AN.00024/) [Institute for Japanese Language and Linguistics](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/AV.00156/) (there's 2 separate entries for 十分 based on the parsed grammatical part of speech), 十分 is used with the に a bit more frequently: 十分に＋動詞 (3686) vs 十分＋動詞 (533+1307=1840).

Note that the second number is probably higher due to some 932 entries that weren't analyzed (未分析).

For ある specifically, it seems that there's a preference for 十分ある (227) over 十分にある (139+2).

Comment: I think this answer is not wrong per se, but 十分 is also an adverb, so this に is optional.

Comment: `十分 is used with the に much more frequently: 十分に＋動詞 (3686) vs 十分＋動詞 (533)` <--「十分(に)○○が○○する」みたいな文型は含まれないんですよね・・ 　「時間は十分あるので」「時間は十分にあるので」どっちもいいと思いますけど。。　ちなみに、[少納言](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/search_form)では、「十分あ+り/る/れ/っ」は229件、「十分**に**あ+り/る/れ/っ」は202件ですね。。

Comment: @Chocolate ああ、「十分」の見出しは二つがある。もう一つの見出しにある「十分＋動詞」は最低限に（未分析が多い）1307結果がある。総計すると、そんなに大きな差ではないみたいです。でも、「十分ある」のほうは結果が多い(227 vs 139+2)。少納言はすごく興味深いです。教えてくれてありがとう！

Comment: @Chocolate, 好奇心ですが、「に」を追加するとどうか意味合いが微妙に異なる気がしますが、かえって自分のセンスは違うかもしれません。ネイティブ・スピーカーとして、「十分ある」と「十分[に]{●}ある」は意味的に完全に同じかどうか、少し説明していただけませんか。